# Inline variable using custom LINQ Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, naming-conventions

I have created a little LINQ extension method that allows me to use a value for very small code without going through the hassle of declaring a local variable.

```cs
public static TReturn Do<TInput, TReturn>(this TInput input, Func<TInput, TReturn> func) 
    => func(input);
```

I use it to inline slightly more expensive expressions that I only use in one place, such as:

```cs
var ImportantValue = MyDatabase.First(e => e.Id == 28131).Do(e => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
    MyOtherDatabase.Add(new Foo(e.FooParameter));
    return e.ImportantValue;
});
```

This is useful as duplicating the `MyDatabase.First(e => e.Id == 28131)` statement would be a performance hit, and creating a local for it would just clutter up the scope needlessly, as it is only ever used in that one spot.
Furthermore this allows for using expression bodies in places where you usually would have to use a block statement, only to have it be two lines long.

However, I am not sure that the name `Do` is very descriptive or useful, and I can't think of any better names for this. As I am using this in more and more code, I would like to give it a proper, descriptive name.

Comment: What's stopping you from giving it a better name, you know the context, how  do you expect help from SO here. Also where's the `Func` return value, how does this compile you need `TReturn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better name than `Do` is possibly `Apply`. But this extension method will be callable for all types of the .NET Framework, so it will clutter the intellisense list of everything. Being on the top of the list would be extra irritating, so I would be inclined to name it with something starting from X, Y or Z, to move it to the bottom. Personally I would prefer not to have an extension method like this at all.